# Import flat file to MS SQL Server 2008 automatically

Tags: sql, file, import

I have a large challenge ahead of me that I will break into 2 problems (not sure if it would be better to pose 2 separate questions).

**After feedback I will move the second problem to a new question.**

Overview:
I have a large list of files being written to a directory (1 per day) that contain a lot of details.
I need to somehow get the contents of the files into as nice a db format as possible to then run queries against.

Problem 1:

Automatically Importing the files into an existing table.
The files are named [DD]-[MMM].txt (eg 27-Mar.txt).

I think this should be straightforward using the Server Import/Export wizard dumping the raw text into single column rows.

Can anyone offer a method for scanning through files and importing new ones only, is there a way to do this using `BULK INSERT`?.

Comment: Would be better as two questions--both require a fairly complex response.

Comment: thought that might be the case, I've edited the original question and will post the follow up question shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recapping the first problem:

- Have a folder
- Contains X number of files
- Have to load data in the files once each

Can you delete the files once the data is loaded? Can you archive them (move them to a different folder, or perhaps just rename them)? Or must it be assumed that they live in the folder foreever, or at least long enough to get in the way of multiple dataload runs?

If the files can be archived after their data is loaded, no big problem. If the files will persist,  then you’d want to log the fact that the file has been loaded and processed, and in subsequent runs for each file found you check the log to see if it’s already been loaded. (Note: since the file name doesn’t contain the year, you’ve got some tricky handling to deal with after 364 days of use. Assume that the current year applies, and you should be good—unless those files do hang around forever, in which case, um, I guess the file gets overwritten with the next year’s pass?)

For a solution using just SQL, you’d need to:

- Load the list of files
- Check it against your LoadLog
- Process the new files

A code snippet outlining how this might be done (where @TargetFolder would be a parameter):

```
DECLARE @Command  nvarchar(2000)

CREATE TABLE #ImportOSFiles (FileName  varchar(128))

SET @Command = 'DIR  "' + @TargetFolder + '\*.txt"  /b'

INSERT #TestFiles
 execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command

DELETE #ImportOSFiles
 where FileName is null
```

(Note that the use of xp_cmdshell may or may not be acceptable to your DBAs and/or architecture.)

Loop through the contents of this table for all files that have not been previously logged, and run a BULK INSERT:

```
CREATE TABLE #LoadData
 (Item  varchar(1000)  not null)


SET @Command = 'BULK INSERT #LoadData
 from ' + @ThisFile + '
 with
  (
    FieldTerminator = ''''  --  No delimiter
   --,RowTerminator = ''    --  Default is CR/LF
  )
'

EXECUTE sp_exectuesql @Command
```

This should produce one unparsed row per line of data. Next step might be to copy it to a more permanent table, so you can associate the file name (date) with the data from that file.

```
INSERT #LoatData_Step2 (FileName, DataRow)
 select @TargetFile, Item
  from #LoadData
```

Then all you have to do is parse the data, a subject of sufficient complexity that I’m not going to get into it here. There might be some complex feature within SSIS that would parse data in this format… and if there is, then you might be better off using SSIS to load the data as well, as it has folder/file looping structures that don’t use xp_cmdshell. But if SSIS can’t handle the data format natively, I think you’d have to do some RBAR parsing, or overly complex user-defined function pattern-matching outer apply joins.

Comment: Unfortunately files are fixed and cannot be renamed/moved after import, I think the solution you've posted may work, keeping a log of files imported. Also I've not thought about what happens when the year ticks over, the system writing the files has only been active since Feb so it will be a while before I can test this.

Comment: Philip has excellent experience in loading files in this manner and I think the solution will work as described.  This problem is also something you can handle with Integration Services, where you create a ForEach File Loop and break it into two steps, 1) check to see if you've already processed the file against the FileLog and 2) load the files that are new.  I think logging each file you processed is the right move regardless of the method.  You will benefit an audit trail.  Flat files can be interesting to deal with.